# nginx phpmyadmin 403 forbidden index.php

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I give up... How to configure nginx to open inedx.php in html/pma folder when i am enter url localhost/pma/ ?

When i enter localhost/pma/index.php it's work.
I am working on windows.

My nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        location /pma/ {
            root   html/pma;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve by Ray`n on irc:
root have to be in server, not location.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

index  index.html index.htm index.php;
root html

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
}
```